# What's up with this rot on our brassicas?

Tags: identification, rot, brassicas

We've got some rot on the kale, cabbage and harvested broccoli plants that we haven't seen in the last 5 years of growing these.

It's been a weird year for my garden here in **Northern VT** all around: fewer pests, waaayy more flies (likely from the horses that moved in next door), and much drier than usual.

The rot definitely smells badly (as all rotting veggies do) and is also attracting flies.

**Rot on terminal bud of kale plant:**

[image]

**Rot on mature ~6" cabbage head:**

[image]

**Rot in recently harvested broccoli stem:**

[image]

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Looks like a bacterial disease

Comment: Perhaps insects have been dining on them and opened them up to/ spread disease to them

Answer (score 1):

This is bacterial soft rot

I have this same problem in my cabbage and and collards. Temperatures are very hot and humid which is ideal for this problem. The rot stinks terribly.

https://gardener.fandom.com/wiki/Bacterial_soft_rot